# How to make sections having a 100% of window's height

Tags: html, css

I've got my page divided into section tags which acts like the website have multiple pages. My problem is that I can't get each section to have 100% of window's height, <strike>and somehow there are gaps between sections</strike>.

I hope I can resolve this without any JavaScript and using percentage so it would be more fluid.

Below is roughly what my page's HTML look like:

```
<div id="nav">
  navigation code here
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
  <section>content</section>
</div>
```

The full HTML & styling can be found at http://theailona.com/doaibu

EDIT: gaps are solved thanks to Gopikrishna & Praveen Kumar

Comment: try the style in h1 `float:left;width:100%;`

Comment: I think you're going to need javascript for this.

Comment: You just need to give this: `section {overflow: hidden;}`! Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

#### CSS Fix:

It is because of the `margin` of `<h1>` tag. Update this in your CSS. And also, the `margin` of `<p>` tag gives you the white-space.

```
h1 {margin: 0;}
.content {overflow: hidden;}
```

#### Alternate Solution:

```
#wrapper > section {overflow: hidden;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add overflow:hidden for sections... please follow below mentioned css hope your problem will solve...

```
#welcome, #service, #clients 
{
    background: url("diamond-pattern.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

#about, #price, #contact 
{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #B8282E;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Set the following height properties in your css**

```
body {
    height:800px;
}

#wrapper, #welcome, #about, #service, #price, #clients, #contact {
    height:100%;
}
```

You can change the height of `body` to any height in pixels and the div/section elements will stretch to 100% of that height.

**Edited**

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
}

#wrapper, #welcome, #about, #service, #price, #clients, #contact {
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This works, but is there any way to not define the body's height in pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Pls change the height of html, body and section to '100%'...So ur css will look like

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  height:100%;
}
section {
  min-height: 65%;
  padding: 0 0 100px 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

I have tried with chrome and it works for me fine :) hope this will help u :)